# ruby check if any item in array exists in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Currently I have this code:

`if !(allowed_params & password_protected_params).empty?`

Which means "if anything in allowed_params is also in password_protected_params". This code works, but I find it a bit obfuscated and not friendly to the next developer that looks at this code.

**Is there another, more readable way to check if anything in one array exists within another array?**

EDIT

The block in question is this:

```
if !(allowed_params & password_protected_params).empty?
  result = @user.update_with_password(allowed_params)
else
  #only update trivial attributes
  result = @user.update_without_password(allowed_params)
end
```

In the end I just added a variable to make it more readable (but still open to better suggestions):

```
needs_password = !(allowed_params & password_protected_params).empty?
if needs_password
  result = @user.update_with_password(allowed_params)
else
  #only update trivial attributes
  result = @user.update_without_password(allowed_params)
end
```

Comment: Yes: `if (allowed_params & password_protected_params).any?`

Comment: I don't mean replacing `empty?`, I'm mainly wondering if there's a more human (read: non-expert in Ruby) readable way to show **"yes, one of the password protected params is in allowed_params"**. In particular, the `[] & []` operator drew blanks from fellow JS devs, and a couple of Ruby devs too.

Comment: All I was suggesting is that Ruby often allows you to avoid negation (`!`) by substituting a complementary method, here `any?` rather than `empty?`. Your use of `&` seems perfectly clear. Sadly, your code being obscure is not the only possible explanation for some Ruby developers being unable to comprehend it.

Answer (score 2):

There is not official synonym for `Array#&`. You can refactor your code into another method, and add a comment:

```
def intersects?(a, b)
 !(a & b).empty?
end

# ...
if intersects? allowed_params, password_protected_params
# ...
```

Otherwise, you may want to extend the `Array` class, and define a method or add  an `alias_method` to it:

```
class Array
  alias_method :intersection, :&    

  def intersects?(array)
    !(self.intersection(array)).empty?
  end
end

[1, 2, 3].intersects? [3, 4, 5] # true
```

Bear in mind that changing core-classes is not a good-practice.

Answer (score 2):

One ruby way could be

```
foo = [1, 2]
=> [1, 2]
bar = [1, 3]
=> [1, 3]
baz = [5, 3]
=> [5, 3]

bar.any?{|element| foo.include?(element)}
=> true
baz.any?{|element| foo.include?(element)}
=> false
```